# Why a breakpoint jumps in my C++ code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

MS Visual Studio 2013.

I see my breakpoint is moving in runtime (C++ code). I had never such behaviour in my C# code, why I get this in C++? How can I solve it?

```
#include <Windows.h>
int main(){
  HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFile(TEXT(""), 0, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
  if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile){
    DWORD err_code = ::GetLastError();
  } // In the IDE I set the breackpoint on this line for err_code value looking...
  return(0); // but in runtime the breackpoint moved to this line.
             // It moved back when the work finished.
}
```

I know what at this case I can set `@err,hr` in the Watch window for the last error info looking, but the breakpoint behaviour is interesting for me.

Comment: `}` isn't really a statement where the debugger can break, so the breakpoint is moved to the next ‘real’ statement.

Comment: I thought about it, but why it works in C#? The `}` is not a statement in C# also. I thought this behavior can be defined by the IDE settings...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS behaves differently with C++ and C#. In the case of C++, the debugger will ignore lines that don't contain any actual code and will keep moving the breakpoint until it hits a line that does contain some code.

A somewhat related behavior is that if you try to debug in release mode, many lines will have been optimized out and even more weirdness will be perceieved unless you know what is going on.

That's just how it works.

In your specific case, you're not really doing anything with the error code, just assigning it to a variable that is local to the `if` statement. In release mode that line and maybe the entire `if` will be optimized away because it has no effect. So you could output the value to the console on the following line or declare `err_code` before the `if`, in which case it will still be 'alive' after the closing `}`.

Comment: Right, but just a heads-up because at some point you will accidentally or deliberately debug a release build.

Comment: Ok, but how C++ programmer will look the value of `err_code` at this case? Especially for it to add an additional line of a code on which it is possible to put the break point - this is a bad way. Also, I don't want to change area of visibility of this variable, carrying its declaration out of block boundaries.

Comment: When breakpoint jumps, the variable will be already invisible.

Comment: *Ok, but how C++ programmer will look the value of err_code at this case* if GetLastError() is called (and not optimized away as well) it's return value will usually (depending on callin convention etc) be stored in the eax register for x86 code. You can see the content of registers in VS.

Comment: Entire if() contains contains function call, and unless compiler knows for sure that it has no side effects (which might be the case, for example, if it is really not a function but a macro which is obviously read-only) - it cannot be optimized away (as it might have side effects).